# Why is PowerShell inserting the current working directory path in front of %USERPROFILE% in this command?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

Here's the situation:

```
PS C:\Users\user> copy %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Thing %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Thing.backup


copy : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\user\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Thing' because it does not 
exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ copy %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Thing %USERPROFILE%\AppData\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\user...\Thing:String) [Copy-Item], ItemN 
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

It's inserting expanded %USERPROFILE% in front of the literal %USERPROFILE%.

What is it doing? How can I prevent that?

Comment: Just a point of clarification: what it's inserting in front of %USERPROFILE% isn't actually the expansion of %USERPROFILE%. It's the current working directory. When I did something similar with PowerShell running in C:\WINDOWS\System32, I got: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In powershell you need to use `$env:UserProfile`:

```
copy "$($env:USERPROFILE)\AppData\Local\Thing" "$($env:USERPROFILE)\AppData\Local\Thing.backup"
```

- And to concatenate strings with variable you need to use the self-expression operator `$()`.
- Actually `copy` is an alias of powershell Cmdlet `Copy-Item`.

---

*Sidenote: If you need to use literal `'%USERPOFILE%'` then use `-LiteralPath` or use single quotes.*

Comment: You don't need the [Subexpression Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#subexpression-operator--)  `$()` with `$env:<variable>` or other string variables in expansion strings --- `"$env:UserProfile\Documents"` is all you need. You only need it to accsss _properties_ of object variables or evaluatiing more complex expressions: `"$env:UserProfile\$($MyObject.FolderName)"`.